# No output from commands when using Cygwin Coreutils 8.14-1

Tags: cygwin

I am having a problem with Cygwin Coreutils 8.14-1.

Each time I upgrade Coreutils (or have another components upgrade Coreutils for me) to version 8.14-1 commands like 'ls', 'pwd', etc. stop outputting any text. The command is accepted, but does not output any text and generates no error.

'ls' and other commands work again when I reinstall Coreutils 8.10-1.

I also receive the following messages when starting Cygwin.

```
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
```

and
    Package: coreutils
        coreutils.sh exit code 127

These messages were reported in this link in Nov 2011.
http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-11/msg00227.html

The message has no followup.

I am running Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 3):

I reinstalled "cygwin base" and coreutils using setup.exe ... things were still broken but I found C:\cygwin\bin\cygwin1.dll.new, I deleted the old cygwin1.dll and renamed this new one. Everything now works again.